# Using HSET or SETBIT for storing 6 billion SHA256 hashes in Redis

Tags: redis

Problem set : I am looking to store 6 billion `SHA256` hashes. I want to check if a hash exist and if so, an action will be performed. When it comes to storing the `SHA256` hash (64 byte string) just to check the if the key exist, I've come across two functions to use

`HSET/HEXIST` and `GETBIT/SETBIT`

I want to make sure I take the least amount of memory, but also want to make sure lookups are quick.

The Use case will be "check if sha256 hash exist"

The problem,

I want to understand how to store this data as currently I have a 200% increase from text -> redis. I want to understand what would the best shard options using `ziplist entries` and `ziplist value` would be. How to split the hash to be effective so the `ziplist` is maximised.

I've tried setting the ziplist entries to 16 ^ 4 (65536) and the value to 60 based on splitting 4:60

Any help to help me understand options, and techniques to make this as small of a footprint but quick enough to run lookups.

Thanks

Comment: ziplist doesn't come for free - it's a tradeoff between memory/cpu so minimum memory & maximum speed is not an option. It's called Space–time tradeoff. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff

Comment: since RAM is much expensive than disk and 6B records will occupy a lot of space, I suggest you store data in some kind of database, it is not as fast, but it is much cheaper

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but you can just use plain Redis keys for this:

```
# Store a given SHA256 hash

> SET 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08 ""
OK

# Check whether a specific hash exists

> EXISTS 2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae
0
```

Where both `SET` and `EXISTS` have a time complexity of O(1) for single keys.
As Redis can handle a maximum of 2^32 keys, you should split your dataset into two or more Redis servers / clusters, also depending on the number of nodes and the total combined memory available to your servers / clusters.

I would also suggest to use the binary sequence of your hashes instead of their textual representation - as that would allow to save ~50% of memory while storing your keys in Redis.